# Login page appears sometimes when I open new page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have recently published my first programmed web application, before that my web application was working fine on a local server which is working on a local network. In the application, the user has to login first in order to be able to open and browse the pages. Now when user login the pages open fine but after a moment when the user opens a page, the login page appears asking to login. this action keeps happening many times.

my login code is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           return View(model);
       }

var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, 
shouldLockout: false);
     switch (result)
     {
         case SignInStatus.Success:
              return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
         case SignInStatus.LockedOut:                        
              return View("Lockout");
         case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
              return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = 
              model.RememberMe });
         case SignInStatus.Failure:
              default:
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "UserName or Password is not correct");
              return View(model);
    }
}
```

In web.config file I wrote:

```
<system.web> 
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <sessionState timeout="30" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
 </system.web>
```

... Please help me with this

Comment: `sessionState timeout="30"` looks like it might mean 'auto logout after 30 seconds'.  Nope, it's 30 minutes.

Comment: Out of interest, why you have created a new project but have targeted a very old version of .net?  4.8 is the latest version and will have loads of features and bug fixes that won't be in 4.5.2 (which I think is EOL in a couple of years).

Comment: I have tried to increase the time to 1200, in order to be sure if the session time out is set in seconds, however, the problem still exists. for the .net version, I have developed the application two years ago and I have no trouble with the version when it was working on the local network.